# Apache Commons FileUpload Stream API not working in Spring 5

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-commons-fileupload

I'm using the Apache Commons FileUpload Stream API and it works perfectly with spring-boot-starter-parent 1.5.14.RELEASE:

```
public ResponseEntity<String> uploadFile(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception
{    
    if (!ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request))
    {
        return responseService.badRequest(request, "file", "Request is not multipart, please 'multipart/form-data' enctype for your form.");
    }

    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
    FileItemIterator iter = upload.getItemIterator(request);

    while (iter.hasNext())
    {
         FileItemStream item = iter.next();
         if (!item.isFormField()) 
         {
            save(item.openStream(), item.getName());

            return responseService.success(request);
         }
    }

    return responseService.badRequest(request, "file", "Must contain a file stream");
}
```

I also have spring.http.multipart.enabled=false set in my properties file.

However, when I upgrade to 2.0.3.RELEASE then the FileItemIterator's hasNext() just returns false.

Has anyone been able to get this working with Spring 5/Springboot 2.0.x?

Comment: I am facing the same issue, hasNext() is always false and I use Spring Boot 2.2.6 with commons-fileupload 1.4. I also have registered a @Bean(name = "multipartResolver") of type CommonsMultipartResolver and setResolveLazily(true). Did you get it working in the meantime?

Answer (score 2):

In your **application.properties** file set:

`spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=false`

If you have not set this you will find it exits appearing to close the stream immediately.

It is possible if you are following an older demo you have set the Spring Boot 1.x value of `spring.http.multipart.enabled=false`.  This has been Deprecated with Boot 2.0

That being said this is a good time to point out two specific resources:

**1.) Spring Reference Documentation**
[Common Application Properties Spring 1.5.15](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.15.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties)

[Common Application Properties Spring 2.0.X](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties)

These docs show changes between the Common Application Properties that you may not have been aware of.  Leveraging an IDE such as IntelliJ it will call this out to you with the red-underlined squiggle with an info-tip (if you happen to be leveraging that).

**2.) Spring Boot Migration Guide**
Check out the [Spring Boot 2.0 Migration Guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#before-you-start).

It receives regular updates and points out these types of pains alongside things such as tooling for migrating `application.properties`, changes in defaults (which are significant), and some underpinnings that have changed.

I highly recommend this if you are migrating an application or just want to understand a little more about how your application will behave differently and some of the why.